# Получить инвентарь пользователя STEAM с помощью Python

Tags: python, парсер, steam, steam-web-api

Встала задача **получать инвентарь пользователя по его трейд-ссылке или по его SteamId**

Пробовала steampy, но после пары-тройки запросов за короткий промежуток времени прилетала ошибка с сообщением о том, что запросов посылаю много, нужно подождать --> такой вариант не подходит

Уверена, что как-то можно даже трейды отправлять автоматически в неограниченном количестве, так как есть много сайтов с кейсами и обменами, которые постоянно отправляют трейды пользователям

Пробовала через Ajax запросы стягивать информацию о инвентаре, все получается, но только на один день, так как в Steam есть сессия, значение которой ежедневно меняется, то есть ссылку в парсере нужно менять ежедневно, что также не особо актуально в моем случае

А вообще суть задачи проста: человек отправляет в программу трейд-ссылку, программа выдает инвентарь или ошибку (если такое возможно) о том, что инвентарь закрыт (или у человека трейд-бан)

Steam web api нужную информацию также не помогает вытянуть...

Заранее спасибо!